Assigning data to a list when it doesn't pass certain checks in R function
I am working with some test data to create a function in R that will loop through the data.table and check each column for certain criteria. The function should group the columns based on known column names, and then loop through those and any value it finds that doesn't fit the criteria for that column should be adding to 'invalid_rows_list'. I have a few extra print statements in my code currently to help debug:
cat(sprintf("Invalid data found in column '%s':\n", col))
        print(data[invalid_rows, .(Row = .I, Value = column_data[invalid_rows])])

Using these print statements, and test data that I know what output to expect, it isn't flagging things correctly. Based on the data I have, it should flag the 'programyear' for row 10 because it has 5 digits (20201) instead of 4; it should flag the 'asian' column for row 9 because it has an A instead of 0, 1, or 9; and it should flag the 'hawaiian' column for row 2 because it has a 2 instead of 0, 1, or 9. The print statements show it is flagging these, but then it is also flagging any of the columns that has fundsexpended in the column name as invalid, even though there are only numeric values in those and that is the only requirement.
The function should be adding the rows with invalid data into the list and printing that list out into a table at the end, but the list prints NULL instead even though the print statements show there is invalid data being found.
Here is the function as I have it currently:
detox_validation <- function(data) {
  setDT(data)
  setnames(data, tolower(names(data)))
  
  # Define columns by type and requirements
  colnames <- names(data)
  agencystaff_cols <- colnames[grepl("agencystaff", colnames)]
  agencypurchase_cols <- colnames[grepl("agencypurchase", colnames)]
  compserviceprovider_cols <- colnames[grepl("compserviceprovider(?!type)", colnames, perl = TRUE)]
  purchaseprovider_cols <- colnames[grepl("purchaseprovider", colnames)]
  numeric_cols <- colnames[grepl("expend|wage|hoursworked|age_", colnames)]
  date_cols <- grep("date|eligibilityext|compdisenrollmsg", names(data), value = TRUE)
  programyear_cols <- grep("programyear", colnames, value = TRUE)
  sex_cols <- grep("sex", colnames, value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
  demographic_cols <- grep("^(amerindian|asian|black|hawaiian|white|
                           hispanic|veteran|disability|adult|adulted|
                           dislocatedworker|jobcorps|wpempservice|youth|
                           longtermunemp|exhausttanf|fostercareyouth|
                           homelessorrunaway|exoffenderstatus|lowincomestatus|
                           englishlearner|basicskillsdeficient|culturalbarriers|
                           singleparent|dishomemaker)$",
                           colnames, value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
  
  # Exclude columns explicitly related to funds expended from certain checks
  funds_expended_cols <- colnames[grepl("fundsexpended", colnames)]
  # Ensure we do not validate these columns with incorrect conditions
  numeric_cols <- setdiff(numeric_cols, funds_expended_cols)
  
  # Initialize a list to store indices of invalid rows
  invalid_rows_list <- list()
  
  # Function to check and record invalid entries
  validate_and_list <- function(col_names, condition, error_message) {
    for (col in col_names) {
      if (!col %in% names(data)) {
        cat(sprintf("Warning: Column '%s' does not exist in the data.\n", col))
        next
      }
      column_data <- data[[col]]
      invalid_rows <- which(!condition(column_data) & !is.na(column_data))
      if (length(invalid_rows) > 0) {
        cat(sprintf("Invalid data found in column '%s':\n", col))
        print(data[invalid_rows, .(Row = .I, Value = column_data[invalid_rows])])
        invalid_rows_list[[length(invalid_rows_list) + 1]] <- data.table(
          Column = col,
          Row_Index = invalid_rows,
          Value = column_data[invalid_rows],
          Message = error_message
        )
      }
    }
  }
  
  # Apply checks
  validate_and_list(numeric_cols, function(x) is.numeric(x),
                    "Must be numeric and not NA")
  validate_and_list(date_cols, function(x) !is.na(ymd(x, quiet = TRUE)),
                    "Invalid date format or value. Expected YYYY-MM-DD or NA.")
  validate_and_list(programyear_cols, function(x) nchar(as.character(x)) ==
                      4 & grepl("^\\d{4}$", x),
                    "Program year must be exactly four digits.")
  validate_and_list(demographic_cols, function(x) x %in% c(0, 1, 9),
                    "Demographic values must be numeric and either 0, 1, or 9")
  validate_and_list(sex_cols, function(x) x %in% c(1, 2),
                    "Sex values must be numeric and either 1 or 2")
  
  
  # Combine all invalid entries into a single data.table
  if (length(invalid_rows_list) > 0) {
    all_invalid_rows <- rbindlist(invalid_rows_list)
    return(all_invalid_rows)
  } else {
    return(NULL)
  }
}

Here is the data I am using to check the function
> dput(check_val)
structure(list(v1 = 1:10, programyear = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 20201), agencycode = c(6L, 35L, 
52L, 42L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 91L, 91L, 91L), applicationdate = structure(c(18444, 
18449, 16743, 18548, 14551, 17403, 12241, 14886, 15216, 15805
), class = "Date"), sex = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), amerindian = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), asian = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "A", "0"), black = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), hawaiian = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), white = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), hispanic = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0), veteran = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), referral = c(19L, 
29L, 1L, 9L, 16L, 29L, 19L, 16L, 16L, 19L), student = c(3L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L), eligibilitydate = structure(c(18467, 
18507, NA, NA, 14573, 17423, 12262, 14886, 15217, 15805), class = "Date"), 
    eligibilityext = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), class = "Date"), oosplacementdate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), oosexitdate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), disability = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), primdisability = c(17L, 19L, 
    18L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), primdisabilitycause = c(34L, 
    2L, 13L, 0L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 10L, 0L, 13L), seconddisability = c(0L, 
    19L, NA, 0L, 8L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L), seconddisabilitycause = c(0L, 
    18L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 0L), disabilitysigcode = c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), twestartdate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), tweenddate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), ipesupportedempgoal = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ipeempstatus = c(8L, 
    NA, 10L, NA, 7L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 8L), ipeprimaryocc = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ipehourlywage = c(0, 
    NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ipeweeklyhoursworked = c(0, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), adult = c(0, 9, 0, 9, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), adulted = c(0, 9, 0, 9, 9, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0), dislocatedworker = c(0, 
    9, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jobcorps = c(0, 9, 0, 9, 9, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), vocrehab = c(1L, NA, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L), wpempservice = c(0, 9, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0), 
    youth = c(0, 9, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), youthbuild = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), longtermunemp = c(0, 
    9, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), exhausttanf = c(9, 9, 0, 9, 0, 
    9, 0, 0, 0, 0), fostercareyouth = c(0, 9, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), homelessorrunaway = c(0, 9, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), exoffenderstatus = c(0, 9, 0, 9, 9, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0), lowincomestatus = c(1, 
    9, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), englishlearner = c(0, 9, 0, 9, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), basicskillsdeficient = c(0, 9, 0, 9, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), culturalbarriers = c(0, 9, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
    0, 0, 9), singleparent = c(9, 9, 0, 9, 9, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0), 
    dishomemaker = c(0, 9, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), migrantfarmworker = c(0L, 
    NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), statedisstudentagerange = c("16;22", 
    "14;21", "14;21", "", "14;22", "14;22", "14;22", "14;21", 
    "14;21", "14;21"), schoolgradecompleted = c(12L, NA, 12L, 
    NA, 0L, 0L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 9L), insecondaryed = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), specialedcertcompdate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), secschooldiplomadate = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, 11855, NA, 17682, NA, 15095, 17344, 18068, NA), class = "Date"), 
    geddate = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), class = "Date"), enrolledinpostseced = c(NA, NA, 0L, NA, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), credprogramenrolldate = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17416, 18506, NA), class = "Date"), 
    completedsomepostseced = c(9, 9, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
    associatedegreedate = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), class = "Date"), bachelordegreedate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), mastersdegreedate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), degreeabovemastersdate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), vtlicensedate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), vtcertificatedate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), otherlicorcertdate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), petsstartdate = structure(c(18428, 
    NA, NA, NA, 17707, NA, NA, 16025, NA, 15895), class = "Date"), 
    jecvragencystaff = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jecvragencypurchase = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jecpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jecvrservicepurchaseexpenditure = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wblevragencystaff = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wblevragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wblepurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wblevrservicepurchaseexpenditure = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ceovragencystaff = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ceovragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ceopurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ceovrservicepurchaseexpenditure = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wrtvragencystaff = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wrtvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wrtpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wrtvrservicepurchaseexpenditure = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), isavragencystaff = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), isavragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), isapurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), isavrservicepurchaseexpenditure = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), vrservicestartdate = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, 16835, NA, 14670, 17458, 12262, 16414, 16463, 15895), class = "Date"), 
    careerservicedate = structure(c(18715, 18489, NA, NA, 18271, 
    18411, 17774, 18660, NA, NA), class = "Date"), gcutvragencypurchase = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), gcutpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), gcutvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), gcutcompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), gcutcompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), fycutvragencypurchase = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fycutpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fycutvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fycutcompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fycutcompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), jcctvragencypurchase = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jcctpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jcctvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jcctcompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jcctcompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), ovtvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ovtvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ovtpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ovtvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ovtcompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ovtcompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), ojtvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ojtvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ojtpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ojtvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ojtcompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ojtcompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), ratvragencypurchase = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ratpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ratvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ratcompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ratcompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), barltvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), barltvragencypurchase = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), barltpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), barltvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), barltcompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), barltcompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), jrtvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jrtvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jrtpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jrtvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jrtcompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jrtcompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), drstvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), drstvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), drstpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), drstvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), drstcompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), drstcompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), mtvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), mtvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), mtpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), mtvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), mtcompserviceprovider = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), mtcompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), rsetvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rsetvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rsetpurchaseprovidertype = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
    ), rsetvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), rsetcompserviceprovider = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), rsetcompserviceprovidertype = c("NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL"), ctvragencystaff = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ), ctvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    ctpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    ctvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    ctcompserviceprovider = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    ctcompserviceprovidertype = c("NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"), assvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), assvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), asspurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), assvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), asscompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), asscompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), dtivragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), dtivragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), dtipurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), dtivrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), dticompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), dticompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), vrcgvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), vrcgvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), vrcgpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), vrcgvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), vrcgcompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), vrcgcompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), jsavragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jsavragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jsapurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jsavrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jsacompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jsacompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), jpavragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jpavragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jpapurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jpavrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jpacompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), jpacompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), stjsvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), stjsvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), stjspurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), stjsvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), stjscompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), stjscompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), sesvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sesvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sespurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sesvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sessetitlevifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sescompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sescompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), irsvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), irsvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), irspurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), irsvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), irscompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), irscompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), bcvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), bcvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), bcpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), bcvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), bccompserviceprovider = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), bccompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), cesvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cesvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cespurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cesvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cessetitlevifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cescompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cescompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), esvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), esvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), espurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), esvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), essetitlevifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tranvragencystaff = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tranvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tranpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tranvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), trancompserviceprovider = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), trancompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), mntvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), mntvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), mntpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), mntvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), mntcompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), mntcompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), rtvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rtvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rtpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rtvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rtcompserviceprovider = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rtcompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), pasvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), pasvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), paspurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), pasvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), pascompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), pascompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), tasvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tasvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), taspurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tasvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tascompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tascompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), rsvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rsvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rspurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rsvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rscompserviceprovider = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rscompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), isvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), isvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ispurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), isvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), iscompserviceprovider = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), iscompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), osvragencystaff = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), osvragencypurchase = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ospurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), osvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), oscompserviceprovider = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), oscompserviceprovidertype = c("", 
    "NULL", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), edfuncleveldate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), secondarydate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), postsectransreportcarddate = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18295, NA, NA), class = "Date"), 
    trainingmilestonedate = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), class = "Date"), skillgainskillsprogdate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), eoprimoccupationstartdate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), exitdate = structure(c(18738, 
    18535, 18501, 18563, 18704, 18681, 18505, 18590, 18648, 18528
    ), class = "Date"), exittype = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), exitreason = c(18L, 19L, 18L, 19L, 17L, 
    17L, 17L, 2L, 18L, 17L), exitempoutcome = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), exitprimoccupation = c("", "NULL", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), exithourlywage = c(0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), exitweeklyhoursworked = c(0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), pecredprogramenrolldate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), pecredattainmentdate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), pecredentialtype = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), appmonthlypubsup = c("0", 
    "0", "_0", "", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0", "2"), appmedinscov = c("7", 
    "1", "_0", "", "0", "1", "0", "7", "7", "1"), exitmonthlypubsup = c("0", 
    "0", "_0", "", "0", "2", "2", "0", "0", "2"), exitmedinscov = c("7", 
    "1", "_0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "7", "7", "1"), ipeinitialdate = structure(c(18473, 
    NA, 16835, NA, 14656, 17458, 12262, 16414, 16463, 15895), class = "Date"), 
    ipeextensiondate = structure(c(NA, 18515, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), enrolledinsecequiv = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), compdisenrollmsg = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18586, NA, NA), class = "Date"), 
    wblevvragencystaff = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wblevvragencypurchase = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wblevpurchaseprovidertype = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wblevvrtitleifundsexpended = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 111111, 0, 0, 0, -111111), wblevcompserviceprovider = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wblevcompserviceprovidertype = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), age_app = c(18, 0, 0, 
    6, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10), age_ipe = c(18, NA, 0, NA, 10, 10, 
    9, 15, 14, 10), age_preets = c(18, NA, NA, NA, 18, NA, NA, 
    14, NA, 10), age_exit = c(19, 0, 4, 6, 21, 13, 26, 21, 20, 
    17), age_vrservice = c(NA, NA, 0, NA, 10, 10, 9, 15, 14, 
    10)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000021fcf475940>)


Can you please come up with a short minimal example that reflects your main coding problem. An example to show how to assign a flag to an existing data frame can be 2 rows long to get the main principle across.

I suspect the problem is to do with variables existing in the wrong environments. Try rewriting the validate_and_list function so that it explicitly returns something, rather than relying on it to silently change the value of invalid_rows_list, which is only defined outside that function.

@AndrewGustar you're correct. A super assignment operator' <<- replacement solves the problem.

@data_life there's a second part.. Let's try to check it too.

@data_life I think Its ok now, check it out.


I suspect the problem is to do with variables existing in the wrong environments. Try rewriting the validate_and_list function so that it explicitly returns something, rather than relying on it to silently change the value of invalid_rows_list, which is only defined outside that function.

@AndrewGustar is right. You need <<- operator inside validate_and_list.
invalid_rows_list is defined one enviroment above the for loop.
Try this:
invalid_rows_list[[length(invalid_rows_list) + 1]] <<- data.table( # <--- HERE
  Column = col,
  Row_Index = invalid_rows,
  Value = column_data[invalid_rows],
  Message = error_message
)

For the second problem, sex_cols regex matches "sex" in "fundsexpended", capturing 37 columns.
I think you missed sex_cols <- setdiff(sex_cols, funds_expended_cols):
# Ensure we do not validate these columns with incorrect conditions
  numeric_cols <- setdiff(numeric_cols, funds_expended_cols)
  sex_cols <- setdiff(sex_cols, funds_expended_cols) # <--- HERE!

The output after these adjustments:
output <- detox_validation(check_val)

> output
        Column Row_Index  Value                                                  Message
        <char>     <int> <char>                                                   <char>
1: programyear        10  20201                Program year must be exactly four digits.
2:       asian         9      A Demographic values must be numeric and either 0, 1, or 9
3:    hawaiian         2      2 Demographic values must be numeric and either 0, 1, or 9

Hope this helps!
